# How can I store the Web Application Username in a DB UpdatedBy or CreatedBy column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using MVC3, C#, EF4.1 and SQL Server 2008.

I have a seperate Domain project for holding the POCO classes for interacting with the DB via EF.

I have implemented "UpdatedOn" using DB triggers. All works fine. However since I need to store the application username rather than the gneric DB username, I require a different mechanism. I have read different posts on here which talks about DBContext.Save(Username) or DI approaches. However I am wondering whether I could add code to my Domain Model project which could do this centrally. I use the Membership Provider, and it is this "Username" that I would need to be passed to the Domain Model.

I would appreciate some advice on a straigh forward approach to this issue.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is understand form your description is that , you need to override SaveChanges() method for dbcontext i.e add logic for record insertion/updation here, so that on every commit to the database there must be an entry to the attribute ( UpdatedBy ).

Comment: Yes, that could be an approach. Just need a centralised approach, and this is one I had not thought of. An example of some code would certainly help me understand your advice more fully. Many thanks.